# Loopback max limit of records returned from server

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback

Is there an option in loopback to set max amount of records returned by server?

For example I have 1000 users in db. I want server return no more then 20 users.
But if someone sends 1 5 10 15 in filter loopback should return that amount.

There is an option "[scope](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Model-definition-JSON-file.html#default-scope)" for a model in loopback. But this option overwrites limit param specified by request.

Comment: You can also use a mixin, like: https://github.com/fullcube/loopback-ds-resultset-limit-mixin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Limit` and `Skip` provided by the loopback

Something like this `/cars?filter[limit]=10&filter[skip]=0`

```
/cars?filter[limit]=10&filter[skip]=10
```

> The following REST requests illustrate how to paginate a query
>   result. Each request request returns ten records: the first returns
>   the first ten, the second returns the 11th through the 20th, and so
>   on…

For a Default implementation you can always do this in the js file of the model

```
Model.beforeRemote('find', function(ctx, instance, next) {
    if (!ctx.args.filter || !ctx.args.filter.limit) {
      if (!ctx.args.filter) ctx.args.filter = {};
      ctx.args.filter.limit = 10;
    }
    next();
  });
```

Comment: I thought this could be done somewhere from config. But anyway thank you